# How to install extention tools for VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

When I try to open install Windows 7 in my virtual machine it shows this error. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

This is the error shown:

[image]

after downloading the extention pack the following error is shown[image]

after installing the extention pack for oracle vm virtual box this error is shown
[image]

Comment: download extension from link below

Comment: i have done the same thing now and those errors are displayed on my screen

Comment: version mismatch , check your version

Comment: how to check it can you give me any command in terminal to get it known sir

Comment: vboxmanage --version

Comment: it says my version is 4.3 but no extention pack is available for that version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download extensions from :

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

VirtualBox extension packages have a .vbox-extpack file name extension. To install an extension, simply double-click on the package file and a Network Operations Manager window will appear, guiding you through the required steps.

Reference :[Here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html)